# Hide components produced by *ngfor

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I'm quite new to ionic and angular so I would like to ask here.
is there a way to hide/remove the components that a ngfor has produced?

my code here produces label and inputs when you click the button add

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let att of anArray; let idx = index">
     <ion-label color="primary">{{att.label}}{{idx+1}}</ion-label>
     <ion-input type="text"  text-right  [(ngModel)]="anArray[idx].value"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>
 <button ion-button   (click)="Add()">Add More</button>
```

what I want to do is to remove all the added labels and inputs of the button "add more" when I click a button in javascript

Comment: You can use `*ngIf` to show and hide items

Comment: can you show how it is done??  I know that *ngIf can be used but it is attached into the component right? how can I attach it to a component that still haven't existed yet??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ngIf:

**Typescript:**

```
show = true;
  add() {
    //....
    this.show = false;
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let att of anArray; let idx = index">
        <ion-label *ngIf="show" color="primary">{{att.label}}{{idx+1}}</ion-label>
        <ion-input *ngIf="show" type="text" text-right [(ngModel)]="anArray[idx].value"></ion-input>

</ion-item>
<button ion-button (click)="add()">Add More</button>
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-uaj1hz)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of a variable and use this with `*ngIf` on the items you wish to hide. When you press the button you toggle this variable to show / hide the desired elements.